# if __name__ == "__main__": failing; why won't __main__ call my classes?

Tags: python, function, class, spyder, program-entry-point

I have been simplifying this code and I am without words. Simply put, the file will not run to call the classes present, and by extension the functions within. The error is something I have never come across and would like some clarity on, if someone could provide it, please.

```
class Server_Design:
    def __init__(self):
        self.intro_input()

    def intro_input(self):
        self.host = input('Host: ')
        self.port = input('Port: ')
        print("y")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Server_Design()
```

COMMAND LINE OUTPUT:

```
    [SpyderKernelApp] ERROR | Exception in message handler:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\ ----\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\comms\frontendcomm.py", line 164, in poll_one
        asyncio.run(handler(out_stream, ident, msg))
      File "C:\Users\ ----\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nest_asyncio.py", line 33, in run
        task = asyncio.ensure_future(main)
      File "C:\Users\ ----\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 677, in ensure_future
        raise TypeError('An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is '
    TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required
    [SpyderKernelApp] ERROR | Exception in message handler:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
```

repeating indefinitely

Comment: How exactly are you running this code?  If you just run it with the Python interpreter as-is it'd be fine, but it looks like it's being run within some kind of async framework, and this is not async code.  (It might be obvious to someone who's familiar with Spyder, but it seems like even to such a person it might be useful to explain how exactly you're using it?)

Comment: I recently had to reinstall python and haven't configured any environment so I'm running it base 3.9.12

Comment: Ya, this code isn't stupid, but I don't know what's going on with my machine. Why are these errors popping up?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What version of Spyder are you using to run your code? The latest Spyder version is 5.3.1. If you use the anaconda distribution you will need to create an env using the conda-forge channel to get the latest version. For that something like this should work: `conda create -n spyder-env -c conda-forge python=3.9 spyder=5.3.1`

Comment: You are running your script via Anaconda Python which acts as its own python distribution. You might be using an older version of Spyder (which is included in Anaconda) with this bug: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/16863
Apparently fixed since version 5.2.0. You might wanna update Spyder to 5.2.0 or higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error was fixed in Spyder **5.2.0** (released on November 2021). Please update to a more recent version by following the instructions posted [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).